# Update dictionary with previously deleted items

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I have two dictionaries. Both declared in a viewController, both based on a model structure class.

```
// ItemDictionary
var ItemDictionary = ItemModel()
var JSONDictionary = ItemModel()
```

JSON data is fed into the JSONDictionary and then this data is passed to ItemDictionary which feeds a table within ViewDidLoad.

```
self.ItemDictionary = self.JSONDictionary
```

All good. The table is nicely populated from JSON data. I can also delete items from the table and the ItemDictionary. However, when I try and add items back by referring to the original dictionary (JSONDictionary) the item has gone.

I understand this is expected. If Dictionary1 = Dictionary2, a new dictionary is not actually created. Only an second address. So if you change Dictionary1, Dictionary2 also changes.

A practical example could be setting a price range. You can reduce the range and have less items displayed on the table. But you can't replace previously deleted items if you wanted to increase the price range. I do not want to recall the JSON script each time I edit the range. Advice appreciated.

Comment: You can add items back into a dictionary. Show your code, please.

Comment: What's the type returned by `ItemModel()`? It sounds like you're using an `NSMutableDictionary` rather than a Swift `Dictionary`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As confirmed by the OP, `ItemModel` is a class and not a `Dictionary`. To fix this you need to make `ItemModel` a real `Dictionary` and thus a value type. This is probably the preferred choice but will be more work.

An alternative would be to add an convenience initializer to the `ItemModel` class that instantiates a new copy of itself and call that instead of setting `self.ItemDictionary = self.JSONDictionary`.

Something like this.

```
init(model: ItemDictionary) -> ItemDictionary {
   // copy properties
}
```

Then create the new copy.

`self.ItemDictionary = ItemDictionary(self.JSONDictionary)`

Later you can reinitialize `ItemDictionary` with the same call.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code out-

```
var dictionary1 = ["name": "Magnus"]
var dictionary2 = dictionary1
dictionary2.removeAll()
print("\(dictionary2) \(dictionary1)")
```

The output is :-

```
[:] ["name": "Magnus"]
```

Thus 2 new dictionaries are being created. If you refer to the Swift documentation, You will find that in swift, references are hardly present.
Some other portion of code might be responsible. Hope this helps :-)

Comment: This is true, `Dictionary` is a value type and copied. BUT what is `ItemModel`? I suspect it is a class and therefore `ItemDictionary` and `JSONDictionary` point to the same object.

Comment: Yeah. If they are objects, rather than deleting data, just remove the reference ItemDictionary ( assign to nil). Thus JSONDictionary will retain the data

Comment: Okay. Then don't delete data of ItemDictionary as I said in my previous comment. Just remove reference. Should work :-)

Comment: And be careful. What you are asking and what you want to ask might not be the same. :-)   "I understand this is expected. If Dictionary1 = Dictionary2, a new dictionary is not actually created. Only an second address. So if you change Dictionary1, Dictionary2 also changes."